# My dropdown won't display, what can i do?

Tags: menu, dropdown, hidden

I am styling my nav-bar, but the drowdown menu hide behind the first section tag.

I use position absolute and with z-index: 9999.

What have i done wrong?

A simple [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tk0Lfe9r/1/) here:

**HTML**:

```html
<html>
<body>
    <nav>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/Logo_white.png" alt="logo"></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Hjem</a></li>
            <li id="ydelser"><a href="#">Ydelser</a>
                <ul class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#"><li>Privat</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>Erhverv</li></a>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Om os</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li class="cta_contact"><a href="contact.html">Kontakt</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <section id="landingpage">

        <h2>Bla bla headline bla bla </h2>
        </section></body></html>
```

**CSS**:

```css
/*NAVIGATION*/
nav {
    height: 100px;
    background: linear-gradient(var(--lightblue),var(--darkestblue));
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}

nav img {
    height: 80px;
    padding: 10px;
}

nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--darkblue)
}

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    background-color: var(--lightorange);
    clip-path: polygon(7% 0, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(7% 0, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    width: 65%;
    height: 100px;
    float: right;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: headline;
}

nav ul li {
    margin-right: 90px;
    font-size: 18px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 30px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

nav ul li:hover {
    font-weight: bolder;
}

.dropdown {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: var(--shadow);
    clip-path: none;
    width: 100px;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 9999;
}
.dropdown li {
    padding-top: 5px; 
    padding-bottom: 5px;  
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    font-weight: 100;
}

#ydelser:hover .dropdown {
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    top: 60px;
  }

/*FRONTPAGE*/
#landingpage{
    height: calc(97.9vh - 80px);
    min-height: 600px;
    width: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(var(--lightblue),var(--darkblue));
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
}



:root {
    --lightblue: #2C4F78;
    --darkblue: #0B2848;
    --darkestblue: #010D2D;
    --lightorange: #F39200;
    --darkorange: #F75C14;
    --whitetext: white;
    --shadow: 6px 6px 10px black;
}

/*GENERAL*/
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```